# Tkinter inserting video into window

Tags: python, video, tkinter

I currently have this code for opening up a .mp4 file from a tkinter program.

```
import os
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title('Video Player')

Fcanvas = Canvas(bg="black", height=600, width=170)


def snd1():
    os.system("C:\\Users\Burky\\Desktop\\Videos\\PermsAndCombsVideo.mp4")

var = IntVar()

rb1 = Radiobutton(app, text= "Play Video", variable = var, value=1, command=snd1)
rb1.pack(anchor = W)
Fcanvas.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

This is good, although the video opens up within quick-time player and is not embedded within the window, is there a way to implement this into the main window instead of it opening up in the quick-time player?

thanks

Comment: @Slayer im using 3.4 which is not compatible

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it. This will continuously update the labels image to be the frames of the video specified. You'll have to handle sound if you want that too. This should get you started.

```
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

video_name = "test.mkv" #This is your video file path
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):

    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I keep receiving permission errors

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d5564e630167522972ba07c8d035f05b

Comment: I am unsure as to why I receive so many errors

Comment: Try running the command prompt as Administrator.

Comment: @Pythonista, could you please refer to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125451/how-to-draw-a-shape-on-top-of-a-playing-video-by-clicking-a-mouse-button-in-open/54125733#54125733) I tend to think you can give some advice!