# How to display VideoFileClip in canvas Tkinter

Tags: python, video, canvas, tkinter, moviepy

I want to display the video in canvas instead opening in a new window.
And I want to know how to stop and pause the video.

```
import pygame
from Tkinter import *
def movie():
    from moviepy.editor import *
    pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
    clip = VideoFileClip('1.mp4')
    clip.preview()    
    pygame.quit()
root = Tk()
root.title("AVATAR")
label = Label(root, fg="dark green")
label.pack()
frame = Frame(root,background='red')
frame.pack()
canvas = Canvas(height=200,width=200)
canvas.pack()
conversationbutton = Button(frame, text='play in canvas',width=25,fg="green", command=movie)
conversationbutton.pack(side = RIGHT)
stopb=Button(root, text="stop").pack()
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635567/tkinter-inserting-video-into-window/36635901#36635901

Comment: I still can't sop it from button and can't display it in specific area like 400*600

Comment: Then, implement the functionality to do so. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: There is a difference between a programmer and beginner. I hope u can understand that and respect that.
I can display video as u commented but I tried to stop it or specify area after researching and i couldn't that is why I asked help!
* I am an one-month python
Thanks again in advance :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks
but it is  a code-helping center for the people who don't know how!