# Python ads within tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ads

I am working on a project. I want to create donate tab where people can donate their money to my projects or watch some ads (so I get some money, and they don't spend any money). Is there any way to make this (I want it to be within a tkinter window)? Do you have any other ideas about handling this?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to tkinter to do that, and nothing built-in to python either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this, but here's a link that maybe helps you.
[Microsoft Python bingad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/get-started-python?view=bingads-13)
Maybe you can use google ads to but I can't find anything for that.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to build it in the window, or would it just be easier to create python webpage.

Comment: If you get text or a picture you can display it in tkinter. I don't read the whole thing on the webpage, but probebly there's a way to do tahat all.,

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it. What the following code does is updates the tkinter frame for every frame in the video, to put an ad in it, just insert the ad video where the video frame is.

I got this solution from [Pythonista's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635901).

```py
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

video_name = "insert_video.mp4" # Enter here the path to the ad
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):

    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, this will play a video, but I want to play an google (or something else) ad. This is not what I wanted.

Comment: Oh, shoot! I have no idea what I was reading or where I even got the concept that you needed to play a video, I think I was thinking like you wanted to play a video ad or something, sorry! A way you can set up a donate tab is make a button redirecting to a website that lets them donate money to you. Again, very sorry.