# Video with sound in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need a way to play video with sound in Tkinter which will not use much RAM.

I tried many libraries and all of them use a lot of RAM (about 10 GB for a 5-minute video). The only thing I found was [bvPlayer](https://pypi.org/project/bvPlayer/). It doesn’t use much RAM, but it creates a video in another window, and I need it to be possible to create other objects, such as labels, here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your video is 1 GB, then the RAM taken by your program will be around 1 GB (more like 1.1 GB).  The size of your video will be roughly the amount of RAM taken.  There isn’t any practical way to use less RAM.

Comment: My video is only 74 MB, but it still uses about 10GB in five minute

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635567/tkinter-inserting-video-into-window).  Admittedly, it's a bit of a pain, and you'll have to handle audio playback too, but it's probably the most reliable.